# Running Javascript in Background as Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a working extension that I turn off and on via a modal page. When I click on my icon the modal page is displayed and I can click the start button to run the extension. However, if I click any where else the modal page closes, which is OK, but the javascript stops running as well. What I want is to click the icon then click the start button and have the modal window close and the javascript keep running until I click the icon again and click the stop button. I have the script set as a "service_worker" in my manifest but that does not seem to help. How can I accomplish this? TIA.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 3,

   "name": "Auto_Select",
   "description": "This extension auto selects Mturk HITs",
   "version": "1.0",

   "action": {
       "default_icon": "auto_select.png",
       "type": "module",
       "default_popup": "auto_select.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "auto_select.js"
    }
}
```

This is the modal HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
"browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
value "popup.html".
-->
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-TYPE"
         content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Auto Select MTurk Extension</title>
      <style>
          body {
             font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
             font-size: 100%;
          }
          #modal {-moz-appearance
             top: 25%;
             width: 270px;
             height: 130px;
             margin: auto;
          }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="modal">
      <div style="text-align:center">
         <strong>Auto Select</strong>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div style="text-align:center">
          <button id="start" type="button">Start Auto Select</button>
          <button id="stop" type="button" disabled>Stop Auto Select</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div style="text-align:center">
         <button id="config" type="button">Configure</button>
      </div>
      <script src="auto_select.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
async function requests(url) {
   try {
   const response=await fetch(url);
   if (!response?.ok) {
     if (response.status==422) {
        // HIT No longer exists
        return(null);
     }
     else if (response==429) {
        tmrs++;
        localStorage.setItem("tmrs",tmrs);
        return(null);
     }
    console.log("caught error: "+response.status);
    return(null);
  }
  const js=await response.json();
  console.log(js);
  return(js);
  } catch(error) {
   return(null);
  }
}

function unique(orig_array,new_array) {
   var unique_array=[];
   for (var i=0; i<orig_array.length; i++) {
     var found=false;
     for (var j=0; j<new_array.length; j++) {
         if (orig_array[i].hit_set_id==new_array[j].hit_set_id) {
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        unique_array.push(orig_array[i]);
    }
  }
  return(unique_array);
}

saved_array=[];
base_url="https://worker.mturk.com";

async function myExtension() {
  var del=config_data.delay;
  const data = await requests(base_url+"/projects.json");
  select_array=unique(data.results,saved_array);
  saved_array=data.results;
  for (let item of select_array) {
     await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, del*1000));
     if (config_data.filters[0].none) {
       res= await requests(base_url+item.accept_project_task_url);
     }
     else if (config_data.filters[0].requester) {
       console.log("Requester filter");
       console.log(config_data.requesters);
     }
     else {
       console.log("Title filter");
       console.log(config_data.titles);
     }
  }
}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click",start);
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click",stop);
document.getElementById("config").addEventListener("click",configure);
tmrs=0;
localStorage.setItem("tmrs",tmrs);

function stop() {
   document.getElementById("start").disabled=false;
   document.getElementById("stop").disabled=true;
   document.getElementById("config").disabled=false;
   run=false;
}

function start() {
   run=true;
   document.getElementById("start").disabled=true;
   document.getElementById("stop").disabled=false;
   document.getElementById("config").disabled=true;
//    document.querySelector("#modal").style.display="none";
   main();
}

function configure() {
   window.open("config.html","_blank");
}

async function main() {
  json_str=localStorage.getItem("Auto_Select_051969");
  config_data=JSON.parse(json_str);
  while (run) {
     console.log("calling exten");
     await myExtension();
     console.log("returned exten");
//      run=false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just for more clarification, the modal you mention is the one which opens when you click the extension icon at the browser tool bar? and your html's name is auto_select.html (which is default_popup in manifest)? If so, then its only natural that you have this problem because popup window terminates once you close them. you would have to move your primary logic to service worker and communicate with popup.html using chrome's message APIs upon button click (for that you can have different js in your popup.html instead of auto_select.js, auto_select.js should be as service worker)

Comment: The popup page runs only when it's shown. You can't use its script as a background script because these are different contexts: there is no access to the document. You need to write a new background script that reads chrome.storage.local and performs the work inside onMessage listener. Your popup script will only write chrome.storage.local and send a message to the background script.

Comment: I think I understand but what launches the background script? Does it get launched automatically when the icon is clicked then waits until the modal script starts or stops it?

Comment: This is more complicated than I thought. I still don't know how the service_worker is launched but how do I wait for a local storage item to change without using a busy loop?